# Spring-EntityManagerFactory, Как подключить JPA?

Tags: java, java-ee, maven, spring-mvc, jpa

Как создать `EntityManagerFactory` в Spring-mvc Maven project. XML или Java (расположение объявления EMF не важно). DB-MySQL. PersistenceProvider то же особо не важен, но хотелось использовать возможности Hibernate, классы собираюсь подключать динамически.

p.s. уже вторую неделю бьюсь с EMF, не как не могу продвинуться дальше.

Comment: Вопрос был решен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для подключения понадобилось создать persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="DLSystemPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.angecrow.dls.domain.model.DLUser</class>
        <class>com.angecrow.dls.domain.model.Question</class>
        <class>com.angecrow.dls.domain.model.Lesson</class>
        <class>com.angecrow.dls.domain.model.StudentsGroup</class>
        <class>com.angecrow.dls.domain.model.Study</class>
        <class>com.angecrow.dls.domain.model.Test</class>
        <class>com.angecrow.dls.domain.model.UserTestResult</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dls"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

После чего объявить DataSource в spring.xml

```
 <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dls"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    </bean>
```

Его передать в `EntityManagerFactory`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="emf">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="DLSystemPU"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.angecrow.dls.domain.model"/>
    </bean>
```

После чего создать `transactionManager` используя `EntityManagerFactory`

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
    </bean>
```

А в него внедрить `JpaDialect`

```
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
```

После чего включил декларативные транзакции с помощью

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Для создания `EntityManager` использовал `@PersistanceContext(unitName="название с persistance.xml") EntityManager em;`

Answer (score -1):

пример объявление EntityManager

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("TDPersistenceUnit");
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter =  new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setShowSql(true);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.td.model.entity*");
    Properties jpaProp = new Properties();
    jpaProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    jpaProp.put("hibernate.query.factory_class", "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory");
    jpaProp.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    jpaProp.put("hibernate.show_sql", Boolean.parseBoolean("true"));
    jpaProp.put("hibernate.connection.charset", "UTF-8");
    jpaProp.put("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "auto");
    jpaProp.put("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "callback");
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProp);

    Map<String, Object> jpaPropertyMap = new HashMap<>();
    jpaPropertyMap.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", localValidatorFactoryBean());
    jpaPropertyMap.put("javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist", "com.td.model.validation.group.PrePersistGroup,javax.validation.groups.Default");
    factoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertyMap);
    return factoryBean;
}
```

пример внедрения

```
@PersistenceContext(name = "TDPersistenceUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

свойство name в аннотации @PersistenceContext это значение установленное в свойство persistenceUnit класса org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.

Таких примеров в гугле полно если у вас что то не получается я думаю стоит описать проблему более подробно.